# c# foreach loop iterations with list from query execution time

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, foreach, asp.net-core-3.1

this is marely an info I need.

When I do a foreach loop with C# iterating over a list as follows:

```
foreach (var record in DbContext.UserRecords.Where(record => record.UserId == user.Id &&
                                                                record.Date.Date == startDate.AddDays(i).Date)
                                                                .ToList())
{
    totHours += record.Hours;
}
```

what is happening exactly at every cycle? does the query happen again so I have N queries to the DB for each item in the list I want or it just does it the first time and then the loop keeps a temporary copy of the data?
I'm trying to optimize times in my ASP.Net project and I was wondering if there was a cleaner/faster way to iterate these long data streams...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're trying to optimize a project, you should run it through a profiler instead of guessing!

Comment: Also, if you're just summing the hours, you can have the query just return the sum of the hours. `totHours += DbContext.UserRecords.Where(/* conditions */).Sum(record => record.Hours);`

Comment: @itsme86 I like this super streamlined approach! thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you call `ToList()` on the `IQueryable` which executes the query and loads the data into memory.

Each iteration is then performed on an in-memory object.

Even without the `ToList()` the query would be executed once, and the data streamed from the database.

Whilst more memory efficient, this holds a lock on the underlying table for the duration of the loop, so you need to be cafeful with that approach.

Comment: I also want to understand a lil. Although i am aware of EF. but particularly in this loop. as `.ToList()` is called. Won't it be called again and again for each iteration?

Comment: According to what you said only once in start actual query will be executed to database and after that on each iteration in-memory fetched record will be used to perform iteration ?

Comment: @RaoHammas No, the expression after `in` is evaluated once to an `IEnumerable`. With `ToList()`, this is a `List<T>` which is an in-memory object. Without the `ToList()` the `IEnumerable` would cause the data to be steamed with each iteration.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thanks sir it was marely a confirmation I needed I thought it was doing it the way you described but I just wanted to make sure... sometimes I do really really horrible mistakes and checking twice is never a bad idea XD